# I am Having Trouble With This Error <Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected>

Tags: c#, game-development

I am trying to add a double jump to my player but I have this error

and I am having problems with curly Brackets Because In The Begging Of The Code Must Contain = public class PlayerController: MonoBehaviour{
and end in }

the code is this if anyone that sees  this knows C# And Can Help You Have My Thanks

```````
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float moveSpeed;
        private float moveSpeedStore;
    public float speedMultiplier;

    public float speedIncreaseMilestone;
    private float speedIncreaseMilestoneStore;

    private float speedMilestoneCount;
    private float speedMilestoneCountStore;

    public float jumpForce;

    public float jumpTime;
    private float jumpTimeCounter;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    private bool canDoubleJump;


    public bool grounded;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckSize;

    private Collider2D myCollider;

    private Animator myAnimator;

    private bool stoppedJumping;

    public GameManeger theGameManeger;

    void Start()
    {

        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();

        myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;

        speedMilestoneCount = speedIncreaseMilestone;

        moveSpeedStore = moveSpeed;
        speedMilestoneCountStore = speedMilestoneCount;
        speedIncreaseMilestoneStore = speedIncreaseMilestone;

        stoppedJumping = true;

    }
    void Update()
    {

        //grounded = Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(myCollider, whatIsGround);

        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckSize, whatIsGround);
        if (transform.position.x > speedMilestoneCount)
        {
            speedMilestoneCount += speedIncreaseMilestone;

            speedIncreaseMilestone = speedIncreaseMilestone * speedMultiplier;
            moveSpeed = moveSpeed * speedMultiplier;
        }
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (grounded)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
                stoppedJumping = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !stoppedJumping)
        {
            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (!grounded && canDoubleJump)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);

                stoppedJumping = false;
                canDoubleJump = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            jumpTimeCounter = 0;
            stoppedJumping = true;
        }
        if (grounded)
        {
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            canDoubleJump = true;
        }
        myAnimator.SetFloat("Speed", myRigidbody.velocity.x);
        myAnimator.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "killbox")
    {
        theGameManeger.RestartGame();
        moveSpeed = moveSpeedStore;
        speedMilestoneCount = speedMilestoneCountStore;
        speedIncreaseMilestone = speedIncreaseMilestoneStore;
    }
} 
 }
``````
```````

Comment: You may want to post the code that's generating this error, also specifying the development platform you're using.

Comment: It appears you have deleted the Namespace, leaving an orphaned brace at the end of file.

Comment: Looks like your `OnCollisionEnter2D` method is _outside_ of your class which is not allowed.  Remove the curly brace that appears just before `void OnCollisionEnter2D`

Answer (score 0):

Check for any additional closing brackets } you might have added by mistake, or maybe a missing one, i'd suggest using an IDE as they are made to detect these types of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Chris Dunaway is correct. It looks like there's an extra curly brace in your code that pushed the last method out of the class.

So this (SO forced formatting):

[...]

```
    myAnimator.SetFloat("Speed", myRigidbody.velocity.x);
    myAnimator.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
}
```

}

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "killbox")
    {
        theGameManeger.RestartGame();
        moveSpeed = moveSpeedStore;
        speedMilestoneCount = speedMilestoneCountStore;
        speedIncreaseMilestone = speedIncreaseMilestoneStore;
    }
}
```

}

Should be this:

[...]

```
    myAnimator.SetFloat("Speed", myRigidbody.velocity.x);
    myAnimator.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "killbox")
    {
        theGameManeger.RestartGame();
        moveSpeed = moveSpeedStore;
        speedMilestoneCount = speedMilestoneCountStore;
        speedIncreaseMilestone = speedIncreaseMilestoneStore;
    }
}
```

}